# How to reset my PATH's and my shell's on mac

Tags: macos, shell, path

My mac has a problem where zsh, bash and all the other shells won't work. And none of my paths are working. But when I create a new user and try my paths there it work's, so I am guessing that it's a path's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sh
echo "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" >> ~/.profile
```

Also, check whether you user has a shell:

`grep $(whoami) /etc/passwd`

That should return something along the lines of:

```
my_user:*:90:90:User:/var/root:/usr/bin/sh
```

If not, add the shell. You could also try to delete -> /add your user again.